# Linear Interpolation Optimization For Sign-ness

Tags: c++, math, optimization, sign, lerp

In a tight loop, I am doing a linear interpolation between two floating point values. However, the only necessary part of the result is the sign (whether the result is negative or positive). I'm doing a typical lerp operation right now, f way between a and b.

```
a + f * (b - a);
```

Is there something more efficient considering I just need to know the resulting sign and not the actual lerped value?

Edit: 'f' is a set of fixed distances along the interpolation, which are known beforehand.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb calculatations are faster than branches (e.g. `if`-statements). Your lerp code is optimal imho.

Comment: Is there one of the parameters a, b, f that is constant ?

Comment: As a Q&D hack, you can get the sign bit as the MSb in the IEEE representation. This spares a test. Anyway, unless the body of the if is really lightweight, any micro-optimization you can do here will go unnoticed.

Comment: @user1043761 Can you please mention the possible range of `f`? Your problem may be further simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate whether interpolated value changes sign at given range:

```
if Sign(a) <> Sign(b) then  //don't forget about zero sign
  change occurs
```

In this case find `f` parameter, where `lerp = 0`

```
a + f0 * (b - a) = 0
f0 = a / (a+b)
```

For smaller values `lerp` has the same sign as `a`, for larger - the same sign as `b`, so you don't need to calculate `lerp` value - just compare `f` with `f0`

Comment: You are trading a multiply for a divide. This isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I consider typical scenario of predetermined `a,b` and evaluation of lerp in some points. So root finding is one-time operation. Then any needed `f` will be compared with `f0`

Comment: As long as the OP hasn't said that `f` is constant, you cannot assume it.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Of course, `f` is not constant, but range ends are constants (I assume).

Comment: In my particular scenario, f will be a fixed set of points along the interpolation so this answer will be marked correct, as it did speed up my app. Respecifying in question